# NXLOG logs are in unicode characters

Tags: logging, unicode, elasticsearch, logstash, nxlog

I have write the code like as following,

```
<Extension charconv>
    Module xm_charconv
    AutodetectCharsets utf-8, euc-jp, utf-16, utf-32, iso8859-2
</Extension>
```

And,

```
<Input sql-ERlogs>
    Module      im_file
    File 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL\MSSQL\Log\ER*'
    ReadFromLast TRUE
    Exec        convert_fields("AUTO", "utf-8"); if $raw_event == '' drop();
</Input>
```

I got the output like following image

[image]

If I expand one of the log I got original log like this,

[image]

Why is it in Unicode characters before expand?

Comment: Looks like UTF-16le was passed to a JSON encoder expecting wide chars or UTF-8. The NUL bytes of the encoded text were encoded as `\u0000` because NULs can't be displayed and are otherwise "dangerous".

Comment: Also I have tried with `convert_fields("AUTO", "utf-16")`. Then the message like `:message=>"Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured."` @ikegami

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Turns out "AUTO" doesn't work reliably. The NXLOG manual on MS SQLSRV hints at what the answer is; you must specify type, such as UTF-16LE.

Check the file contents with a hex editor and compare to MS's chart https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
Exec    $Event = convert($raw_event,"UTF-16LE","UTF-8"); to_json();
```